# dput(as.Date(df$date)) shows up as number

Tags: r, date, datetime, dput

I have a dataframe `df` with date column `date`, `df$date`:

`[1] "2013-01-31" "2013-02-28" "2013-03-31" "2013-04-30" "2013-05-31" "2013-06-30"`, etc.

When I `dput(as.Date(df$date))`, it shows up as numbers:

```
structure(c(15736, 15764, 15795, 15825, 15856, ...), class = "Date")
```

I also try: `dput(as.Date(df$date, origin="1970-01-01"))`, it returns same result.

How could I get the result as follows:

```
structure(c("2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-31", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-31", "2013-06-30", ...), class = "Date")
```

Comment: Why? It's an internal representation of dates which is unambiguous (for R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-issue (unless for some unknown reason you care about how the value is encoded in the dput output), since when you load the dput output, the date is returned. It's just the way the data is coded - that `class = "Date"` means R can interpret the numerical value as a date.

```
structure(c(15736, 15764, 15795, 15825, 15856), class = "Date")
```

```
[1] "2013-01-31" "2013-02-28" "2013-03-31" "2013-04-30" "2013-05-31"
```

Comment: Thanks, so may I ask how could we convert `df$date` to `c("2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-31", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-31")`?